# Executing Python via Pyodide in Github Pages

Tags: javascript, python, web-applications, github-pages, pyodide

Is there any way I can run python in github pages? Specifically through [Pyodide](https://pyodide.org/en/latest/index.html) because I am using pandas. I know github pages is only meant to serve static pages using HTML/CSS/JS but I was wondering if there is a workaround with pyodide given that it is compiled in Javascript.

I am trying to build a small web application which has a username entry box that once submitted, calls some data from an API, processes in pandas and displays some visualizations (either using a JS library like Chart.js or Zingcharts, or otherwise matplotlib / seaborn)

Comment: Check out this [tutorial](https://medium.com/swlh/python-in-web-easy-5f7de3813055)

Comment: I created [this react+pyodide template](https://github.com/xhlulu/react-pyodide-template), which includes instructions to host on github pages

Answer (score 5):

WebAssembly is run client side, so you can make a Pyodide application hosted on Github Pages (or any other hosting for static assets).

For downloading Pyodide packages/dependencies, the easiest is to use the JsDelivr CDN (cf pyodide docs), but you can also host them on Github pages if you prefer. The corresponding asset size should be within [allowed usage limits](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#usage-limits).